# Display the number of before held training

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am new in Laravel and I used Laravel 5 for my project.
My specification is count the number of before held training according to category of training so i used join and group by and count function to get the number before held training:

In my controller code is as below:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Request;
use App\Training;
use App\Schedule;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\TrainingRequest;
use Carbon\Carbon;


  class TrainingController extends Controller
  {
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */

public function __construct(){

$this->middleware('auth',['only'=>'index']);
}
public function index()
{
    //


    $training=Training::all();

        $before_held=Schedule::join('training','training.id','=','schedule.training_id')
                 ->groupBy('training.category')->where('schedule.training_end_date','>=',carbon::now())->get();
   // echo count($before_held);
   //die();


    return view('Training.index',compact('training','before_held'));
}
```

In View:-

```
 <td><a href="/training/before_held">{{count($before_held)}}</a></td>
```

This always show 0 count in the table like this:-

```
|category|Held Before|
|test    |   0       |
|test    |   0       |
```

But I need count two if training_end_date greater than or equal to current time.

SO I am thankful if anyone can solve this issue.

Comment: Shouldn't `count($before_held)` actually return 1 instead of 0 in the first place? If you group by a column you should have exactly one row selected in the end for the table you showed. Assuming there was anything joined, of course.

Comment: so how to count training_end_date as per category